Is 左右 read as 左右【さゆう】 or 左右 【そう】or 左右 【さう】or 左右 【とかく】?
I found the sentence...
戦力【せんりょく】は艦船【かんせん】や武器【ぶき】だけではなく、これを活用【かつよう】する兵士【へいし】の力【ちから】に左右【さゆう】される
Fighting potential depends not only on ships and weapons, but also on the soldiers who use them.
https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/column/civil02/20240605-OYT8T50029/
The furigana generator says 左右【さゆう】
Did it produce the correct reading?
I ask because 1) the machine translation into English looks a bit free, and 2) the wwwjdic says...
左右 【さゆう; そう; さう】 (1) left and right; right and left; (2) (asserting) control; influence; domination; (3) one's attendants; people accompanying one; (4) (serving at someone's) side; (5) equivocation
とかく 《兎角; 左右》(1) (doing) various things; (doing) this and that; (2) being apt to; being prone to; tending to; (3) at any rate; anyhow; anyway; (4) all sorts of (negative things); various...

In modern Japanese, さゆう is the only correct option. さう and そう can effectively be seen as obsolete. In fact, even in more historical contexts, I have mostly only seen the latter two in the context of ご左右 (“command, instruction“), which is not what we are talking about here.
とかく, per the dictionary entry you have supplied, does not possess the meaning that we want ([of an important variable] “to change, to determine”).

Thank you! Too bad the electronic dictionaries do not provide the kind of information you just gave me, which would eliminate my having to bother people on StackExchange with my questions

@NedReif there are dictionaries with frequency information for readings (though they should be taken with a grain of salt due to the chance for parsing errors). Also, さゆう is just an extremely common word you're sure to be exposed to a lot.
